# Link Object's property to Actions

Tags: python, properties, nla-editor, actions

Is it possible to enhance the animation(where all animations are instanced as unique Actions from the Nla Editor)  **by changing the object's property** (like material color etc)  **whenever a particular action is instanced ?**(eg.For a battle scene ,whenever a  slashing action is played the sword material color changes to "Red" .)

Comment: Sounds like a job for drivers.  If "ob" has the actions,  add a custom property  `ob["slash"]` Key in a value of say 1 in slash actions zero in others. Drive the material color with `ob["slash"]`